# Receive data of multitouch events from laptop's touchpad

Tags: java, multi-touch, touchpad

I'm working on writing a program that controls Android device (via USB cable and the Android-SDK toolset).

The program is written in Java, and is addressed for Windows platforms.

The idea is that I get a screenshot of the device's screen every few seconds and show it in a Frame, and then I can simulate taps and swipes on the device's screen using the PC mouse.

So far everything is working as expected.

The thing is I now want to enable the ability of simulating multitouch events on the device, and I was thinking - why can't I receive such events from a multitouch device such as the touch-pad every modern laptop comes with.

How can I do it? is that hardware dependent? Platform dependent? Would I need to implement some sort of interface with drivers for every touch-pad I want to support, or is there a way to do it simply like I write a regular mouse listener?

Comment: I can't answer your question completely, so I just write a comment. I know it's hardware dependent, as many touchpads in laptops are not multitouch enabled. It could be listed in the specs but it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Thanks @Sascha. I guess your comment stands also for multitouch stylus, am I right?

Comment: By stylus you mean an "old school" pen? Sorry could not resist ;) Yes, that is also related to stylus. But: stylus/pen capabilities should be visible in the properties of your PC (Control Panel\System and Security\System)